# Can´t remove white spaces above and below images

Tags: php, html, css

I upload images to my website but they don´t fill the box and appears a white space above and below images. It occurs in the main images of the products and thumbnails too. I have used a lot of things in CSS, like: display: block; text-align:center; width:100%; height:100%....but nothing as a result. Only if I use a resolution of 800x800px it fills the blocks (as you can see at thumbails).

Here´s the link to my website http://planarte.es/prestashop/index.php?id_product=9&controller=product&id_lang=3

Answer (score 0):

The white spaces are part of the image : http://planarte.es/prestashop/img/p/6/6/66-cart_default.jpg

This is not a CSS issue.